# How count different key according its value in mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, database

I've a collection in mongo and need create a query with statistics for example number of register by name and number of register by key privated that is true and so on.

```
{
  _id : 123,
  name: capnis
  privated: true
},
{
  _id : 124,
  name: capnis
  privated: false
}, ....
```

when try do the query in mongo don't know how get this result

```
{name: capnis,
 total: 2,
 totalprivatedtrue:1,
 totalprivatedfalse:1 }
```

here i get total but how can get the other?

```
.aggregate([
  {$match: {name: "$name"} },
  {$group: {_id:"$name", total: {$sum:1} } }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator in the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline step to evaluate the counts based on the `privated` field, something like the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([    
    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": "$name",             
            "total": {
                "$sum":  1
            },
            "totalprivatedtrue": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ "$privated", 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            "totalprivatedfalse": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$privated", false ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            }
        }  
    }
])
```